# How to rotate a Qt5 application using the linux framebuffer?

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, framebuffer

I have an embedded linux application running directly on the linux framebuffer (no x-Windows).  We now have to physically rotate the display 180 degrees.  How do I get my Qt application to rotate so it doesn't appear upside down?  I saw reference to using the following option:

```
 -platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0:rotation:180
```

However, the rotation option seems to be ignored.

Using Qt 5.9.2 on Ubuntu server 16.04.6

Comment: Have you tried going into `Projects` on the left side panel, then select `Run` and add `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0:rotation:180` to the Run  Environment?

Comment: @RickPat I'm not using QT creator on my embedded system, but I tried that environment variable and it also had no affect on the rotation

Comment: ok, are you using qwidgets or qml?

Comment: @RickPat QWidgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle it on application level. With QML thats easy, but with QWidgets the best I could come up with is to render the Widget on a `QGraphicsScene` and rotate it like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
    view->setGeometry(w.geometry());
    view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    scene->addWidget(&w);
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->show();
    view->rotate(180);

    //w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It seems a bit glitchy, but you could give it a try.

Also I think the correct syntax is `-platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0:rotation=180` note the `=` instead of `:` 
**Edit:** but that did not make a difference for me either.

Comment: This appears to do what I need, thanks!
Also, the rotation=180 vs rotation:180 made no difference.  It still seems like there should be a simpler method than using the QGraphicsScene, but I will go with what works.